# Dynamically altering URL in react app based on values in object

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to replace the params of a url with values of an object if the param is the same as a value within the object.

I've got it so that it replaces the values but its just creating an array with 2 items and im looking to basically "merge" them together to create a URL.

Any help is much appreciated!

where `urlData` consists of something like this which is being passed in:

```
[
    {
        param: ':userId',
        value: userId || '',
    },
    { param: ':messageId', value: messageId || '' }
]
```

And my Menu looks like this:

```
{menu?.map((menuItem, index) => {
    const { title, path } = menuItem
    const finalPath = urlData?.map(
        (url, index) =>
            path.includes(url?.param)
                ? path.replace(
                    url?.param,
                    url?.value
                  )
                : path
        )

    console.log('final', finalPath)

    return (
        <Link
            to={finalPath}
            key={index}
            className={
                pathname === finalPath ||
                finalPath.includes(pathname)
                    ? 'active'
                    : ''
            }
        >
            {title}
        </Link>
    )
})}
```

My current response:

```
[
    "/app/messages/be493d77/:messageId",
    "/app/messages/:userId/2cd4df7d"
]
```

What im looking for:

```
    "/app/messages/be493d77/2cd4df7d"
```

Comment: When you map `urlData` array the result will be an array of equal length. What is the starting value you are trying to replace path segments of?

Comment: the starting value is `/app/messages/:userId/:messageId` and id like to replace the params with the values

Comment: Oh, so you just want to inject the values from the `urlData` array into the `"/app/messages/:userId/:messageId"` path string?

Comment: Yeah, thats correct. Basically if the param is in the `path` then replace it with the corresponding `value` in that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping the `urlData` array which results in an array of equal length, reduce over the array.

Example:

```js
const userId = "be493d77";
const messageId = "2cd4df7d";

const path = "/app/messages/:userId/:messageId";

const urlData = [
  { param: ":userId", value: userId || "" },
  { param: ":messageId", value: messageId || "" }
];

const finalPath = urlData.reduce(
  (path, { param, value }) => path.replace(param, value),
  path
);

console.log(finalPath);
```

Alternatively you could use the `generatePath` utility from `react-router-dom`. This requires the `urlData` `param` values to match the param name instead of the path's string literal.

Example:

```
import { generatePath } from "react-router-dom";

const urlData = [
  { param: "userId", value: userId || "" },
  { param: "messageId", value: messageId || "" }
];

const finalPath = generatePath(
  path,
  urlData.reduce(
    (params, { param, value }) => ({
      ...params,
      [param]: value
    }),
    {}
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Drew for the help, very much appreciated. This did the trick! Small oversight at 3:30am...

Comment: @Nick No worries, we've all been there. Cheers and good luck!